# ¿Hay una forma diferente de ordenar contenedores en docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Me he estado preguntando si hay alguna otra forma de ordenar los contenedores a parte del `docker ps -a`, como por ejemplo darles una id diferente, como ejemplo si se creara el contenedor asignarle la id 1 automáticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo se puede asignar un nombre a los contenedores, servicios, etc
pero no se puede asignar el id...